# return result of XPath function via SimpleXML

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

It seems that PHP SimpleXML XPath doesn't allow to get results of XPath functions:

```
$s = new \SimpleXMLElement('<test><node>A</node><node>B</node></test>');
var_dump($s->xpath("count(node)"));
```

Returns an empty array:

```
array(0) {
}
```

While Using DOM returns the expected value 2:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<test><node>A</node><node>B</node></test>');
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate("count(node)"));


float(2.0)
```

Is there a way to do the same directly with SimpleXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's SimpleXML only works on queries which return nodesets. `count(...)` returns a scalar value which is not supported. Use DOMXPath which is much more capable or count the objects in the result array:

```
var_dump(count($s->xpath("node")));
```

> int(2)

Comment: I have feared that this is the answer. Thanks anyway.